# Display calculated price by catalog promotion rule on products list page

Tags: magento-enterprise, catalog, promotions, catalog-price-rules

Is this a way to display product's calculated price by catalog promotion rule (not special price) on products list page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $product->getFinalPrice() ?>
```

should do the trick.